# I followed Blender Made Easy's tutorial and rendered this first frame and it's blurry as heck

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, ocean-simulation, motion-blur

I followed the [Blender Tutorial - Creating a Stormy Ocean](https://youtu.be/oysCSbhXYBo) by *Blender Made Easy*, rendered the first frame and it's blurry as heck. A photographer said that, in photography, motion = blurry. But the viewport is perfect. The tutorial did not cover how to render anything. So I'm just rendering PNGs over and over without success (some are completely black, and others look like a total blur). How do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled *Motion Blur* in the render settings? By the way *Blender Made Easy* has a dozen of tutorials. How should we know which one you're talking about and what it is about? A few more details would help to answer your question a lot.

Comment: oh, It's literally that same ocean animation. it's frame by frame the same. even the splash screen is that picture. I just noticed I did tick motion blur in setting and have it set to 0.5. is that why it looks sooooooooo blurry?

Comment: It is as you wrote *"... in photography, motion = blurry."*. The *Motion Blur* setting simulates this. If the ocean or the camera moves fast the animation gets blurry like in reality.

Comment: Maybe you also ticked *Depth of Field* in your camera settings?

Comment: No. I checked. No depth of field was checked. I asked someone else and showed the original tutorial's opening animation, and he said it had almost zero or 0.1 motion blur which he said is uncanny valley. So the simple question is, what's the setting for "reality" in animation? Some guy in a video showed 2 different hollywood movies, braveheart vs private ryan. braveheart was all blurry "to simulate chaos". private ryan was way less blurry to show the actor's emotions. I just want reality.

Comment: Thank you guys. I finally made this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8XyJXRKLaw I owe it all to you.